# Searching for a folder in outlook folders: MULTIPLE OUTCOMES

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I would like to choose a particular mailbox (inbox, archive mailbox, etc.) and find a particular folder by name.

I would like to have the option which will not show me only one result but if in a particular inbox there will be two same subfolders, will show me the first one, if I accept it than case closed, if not I can go to the next result.

```vb
Private MyFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Private MyFolderWild As Boolean
Private MyFind As String

Public Sub FindFolder()
  Dim Name$
  Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders

  Set MyFolder = Nothing
  MyFind = ""
  MyFolderWild = False

  Name = InputBox("Enter the Folder Name that you would like to find:" + vbCrLf + vbCrLf)
  If Len(Trim$(Name)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
  MyFind = Name

  MyFind = LCase$(MyFind)
  MyFind = Replace(MyFind, "%", "*")
  MyFolderWild = (InStr(MyFind, "*"))

  Set Folders = Application.Session.Folders
  LoopFolders Folders

  If Not MyFolder Is Nothing Then
    If MsgBox("Do you want to go to this folder ?" & vbCrLf & MyFolder.FolderPath, vbQuestion Or vbYesNo, "TheTechieguy.com - Found your Folder:") = vbYes Then
      Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = MyFolder
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "The folder you were looking for can not be found.", vbCritical, "TheTechieguy.com - Folder NOT found:"
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub LoopFolders(Folders As Outlook.Folders)
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Found As Boolean

  For Each F In Folders
    If MyFolderWild Then
      Found = (LCase$(F.Name) Like MyFind)
    Else
      Found = (LCase$(F.Name) = MyFind)
    End If

    If Found Then
      Set MyFolder = F
      Exit For
    Else
      LoopFolders F.Folders
      If Not MyFolder Is Nothing Then Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Sum up:
It will be good enough if script will find particular folder in particular inbox or functional mailbox, which I will point, and show every result which matches the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

To select a folder use Pickfolder.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869969%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Confirm the correct folder was found before leaving LoopFolders, not after.

Move the test inside LoopFolders and test F.

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to go to this folder ?" & vbCrLf & _ 
  F.FolderPath, vbQuestion Or vbYesNo, _
  "TheTechieguy.com - Found your Folder:") = vbNo Then

    Found = False

End If

If Found Then
```